# `FAISSDocumentStore` in `haystack` always returns empty results

Tags: python

I am new to `haystack` and I am using `FAISSDocumentStore` and `EmbeddingRetriever` to implement a QA system. This is my code:

```
from haystack.document_stores import InMemoryDocumentStore, FAISSDocumentStore
from haystack.nodes import TfidfRetriever, DensePassageRetriever, EmbeddingRetriever
from haystack.nodes import FARMReader, TransformersReader
from haystack.nodes import FARMReader
from haystack.pipelines import ExtractiveQAPipeline
import requests
import pandas as pd

class NeuralSearch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.HIDDEN_DIMS = 384
        self.FAISS_INDEX = "Flat"
        self.path = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deepset-ai/COVID-QA/master/data/faqs/faq_covidbert.csv"

    @property
    def document_store(self):
        doc_store = FAISSDocumentStore(
            embedding_dim=self.HIDDEN_DIMS, faiss_index_factory_str=self.FAISS_INDEX
        )
        
        return doc_store

    @property
    def retriever(self):
        retriever = EmbeddingRetriever(
            document_store=self.document_store,
            embedding_model="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
            use_gpu=False,
        )
        
        
        return retriever

    def load_data(self):
        data = requests.get(self.path)
        open("small_faq_covid.csv", "wb").write(data.content)

        df = pd.read_csv("small_faq_covid.csv")
        df.fillna(value="", inplace=True)
        df["question"] = df["question"].apply(lambda x: x.strip())

        questions = list(df["question"].values)
        df["question_emb"] = self.retriever.embed_queries(texts=questions)
        df = df.rename(columns={"question": "content"})

        # # Convert Dataframe to list of dicts and index them in our DocumentStore
        docs_to_index = df.to_dict(orient="records")
        self.document_store.write_documents(docs_to_index)
        self.document_store.update_embeddings(self.retriever)
        self.document_store.save("testfile_path")
        ss = FAISSDocumentStore.load(index_path="testfile_path")
        
        # print(docs_to_index)
        return docs_to_index, ss

    @property
    def reader(self):
        reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path="deepset/roberta-base-squad2")
        return reader

    @property
    def pipeline(self):
        pipe = ExtractiveQAPipeline(self.reader, self.retriever)
        return pipe

    def predict(self, query):
        prediction = self.pipeline.run(
            query=query,
            params={"Retriever": {"top_k": 10}, "Reader": {"top_k": 5}},
        )
        return prediction

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = NeuralSearch()
    q = "What is a novel coronavirus?"
    print(n.predict(q))
```

my problem is that the `FAISSDocumentStore` always returns empty predictions as follows:

```
{'answers': [], 'documents': [], 'root_node': 'Query', 'params': {'Retriever': {'top_k': 10}, 'Reader': {'top_k': 5}}, 'query': 'What is a novel coronavirus?', 'node_id': 'Reader'}
```

How to fix it? and are there any tutorials on how to use `FAISSDocumentStore`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that you do not load the base itself here:

> `ss = FAISSDocumentStore.load(index_path="testfile_path")`

Try adding a path to the configuration, it has a path to the base:

```
document_store = FAISSDocumentStore.load(index_path="file.faiss", config_path="file.json")
```